# Docker: network between linux and window container

Tags: docker, linux-containers

I have a window container with an asp.net webapi app (not core) and second (linux) container with an sql server.

In linux container I have created new network:

```
docker network create budget-app-network
```

and created container:

```
docker run -d --name budget-db -p 11433:1433 --network budget-app-network --network-alias mssql budget-db
```

When I want to enable the window container by using:

```
docker run -d --name budget-app -p 888:80 --network budget-app-network budget-app
```

I got an error says:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network budget-app-network not found.
```

I can't find how to connect the web api to the database. How can I make to communication? I believe it would work if I would have an two linux or two windows containers and not mixed them.

Answer (score 2):

#### Background

When you are running Windows and Linux container on a windows host, you have two docker engines running. One engine is running natively on windows and is running the windows containers, and one inside a virtual machine (Hyerp-V) running the linux continuers. This is discussed in the following thread on github

#### Solution options

Because they are running on separate hosts, you need to manage the network in the same manner.

- The easiest approach is to allow the containers to communicate trough the published ports, tough the windows host (routing the traffic trough the public IP of the host).
- Also, you can use docker-compose as described in this [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/mixing-windows-and-linux-containers-with-docker-compose/) and allow docker-compose to create the network bridge between the VM containers and the windows contaierns.
- Finally you have option to create a swarm by installing a linux and windows VMs (Hyper-V) and create a mixed-OS swarm. This is the most complicated option and the drawback is that you will have additional overhead from the additional windows machine running in hyper-v. The details are described in Microsfot's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/swarm-mode)

Comment: The blog post doesn't work on Win11 22H2 / Docker Desktop 4.22.1. The `platform` option results in docker compose to fail. I can connect to the linux container from the Win11 host but I cannot connect to it from a windows container. Any tips?